# Login and Register with API using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am writing code in android studio to login and register user in app by fetching details from API.
but getting this error on Clicking button.

java.lang.illegalStateException:Expected BEGIN OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY .

Note(I am taking email and password for login ||  first name ,email and password for registration
also used PHP for database)

I have tried retrofit2 for this code.
I am cannot figure out the what is the Problem .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the question guidelines [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For your question regarding retrofit, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Kind Regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.